# Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to grab a ParseRelation of user's who have joined a group. I had no problem until I added login with Facebook. Now, I get the error of "Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated" when trying to add a user to the relation and then saving the ParseObject. I can join groups created by people who did not log in with Facebook and I can join groups that I created (I'm logged in with FB), but get the error with group's created by another user who logged in with Facebook.

```js
mJoinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
  Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ParseObject group = mGroups.get(getAdapterPosition());
    mJoinedRelation = group.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_JOINED_RELATION);
    mJoinedRelation.add(mCurrentUser);
    group.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

      @
      Override
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          Toast.makeText(mContext, "You have joined the group!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
            .setMessage(e.getMessage())
            .setTitle(R.string.login_error_title)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
          AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
          dialog.show();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Where does mCurrentUser come from? Is this user already saved in the databse? If the user doesn't exist in the database, you'll get this error. Also, please be aware of the security restrictions for User class that Parse has in place. If you are logged as user A, you cannot modify user B. Not sure if that's what you're trying to do as it's difficult to know only with the pseudo code you provided. Could you please try to add more code and explain the whole flow?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm not trying to modify any users. All I am trying to do is add a pointer to a user to a relation in another class. I was able to fix it by taking the user profile JSON object that you get from Facebook and saving each individual piece to Parse in a separate column in the user class, instead of saving the JSON object itself in a column. I don't know why this fixes it, but it seems, that having a JSON object causes a problem. Even leaving the code exactly the same and just deleting the JSON object from Parse allows the user to join the relation. Maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the ACL column on your User class on parse.com, you will see that it has Public Read but what it doesn't have is Public Write so you cannot update row information if you are not logged in as that user. I believe you will have to add Public Write to the ACL of that user if you want to be able to update while not logged id, although I wouldn't recommend it. Another solution is to create a ParseObject to store non-login information, that way you will be able to update it from anywhere since the ACL will be set up to Public Write by default.